# runtime error 9 subscript out of range while running in 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error in excel 2016 but it working fine in 2013
at line

`Set destSheet = Workbooks(newSnameQ).Sheets(2)`

Code:

```
  For i = 1 To lastRowSh1
    If destSheet.Range("C" & i) <> "" Then
        destSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Auto Match"
    End If
Next i

'Transfer the LGA processed data from sheet "LGA_Data"
Sheet3.Select
   Set destSheet = Workbooks(newSnameQ).Sheets(2) 
   lastRowSh1 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
If lastRowSh1 < 25 Then
```

Comment: Is `newSnameQ` some constant or it's calculated somehow?

Comment: Are you mixing .xls and .xlsx workbooks?

Comment: newSnameQ = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Capturing the saved workbook name
    Workbooks(newSnameQ).Sheets(1).Select

Comment: @Jeeped yes.. I am  mixing .xls and .xlsx workbooks

Comment: What is the eror that you got?

Comment: @nishitdey runtime error 9 . subscript out of range.  this is the line which is highlghted while debugging -   Set destSheet = Workbooks(newSnameQ).Sheets(2) .

Comment: can you let us know what is the value in newSnameQ? Is it the full file name? is the file open? Is it only the filename, excluding the folderpath?

Comment: Can you try activating the book first, then setting the sheet? I know it does not answer your question, but looks like the workbook is causing the error.

Comment: @Lowpar  newSnameQ = Left(Sheet1.Range("AE20"), 7) & "-" & "SDU-Quality sheet" & "-" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmmss")  'Capture the short name of the Quality file
        newNameQ = thisPath & "\" & Left(Sheet1.Range("AE20"), 7) & "-" & "SDU-Quality sheet" & "-" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmmss") 'Long name of the quality file

Comment: Default setup of Excel 2016 tends to have just one sheet unless manually added which was three sheets in Excel 2010 (and I have not used 2013). Are you creating the workbook on the fly?

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij i changed the default setting to 3 and it worked. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @saurabhkumar Great! I'd suggest adding a small function for checking and adding the sheet rather than changing settings. It will be good especially if you intend the code to be deployed and used on several computers.